# MongoDB Text search fails for stop words

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do a query in my collection, but its not returning anything.

Here's my `query`:

```
{'$match': {'$text': {'$search': 'a'}}}, 
{'$group': {'_id': {'texto': '$texto'}, 
            'somanumero': {'$sum': '$numero'}}}
```

My collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555cdc4fe13823315537042d"), "texto" : ObjectId("555cdc4fe13823315537042c"), "numero" : ObjectId("555cdc4fe13823315537042e") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555cdc5ee13823315537042f"), "numero" : 5, "texto" : "a", "lattexto" : "-15.79506", "lontexto" : "-47.88322" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555cdc6ae138233155370430"), "numero" : 10, "texto" : "a", "lattexto" : "-15.79506", "lontexto" : "-47.88322" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555cdc73e138233155370431"), "numero" : 3, "texto" : "b", "lattexto" : "-15.79506", "lontexto" : "-47.88322" }
```

And here's my text index:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "texto_text",
    "ns" : "OSA.teste_texto",
    "default_language" : "portuguese",
    "weights" : {
        "texto" : 1
    },
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

When i use `$group` or `$match` alone, it works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the response when you just do the `$match`? A common mistake is not realizing that aggregations act as a pipeline, and the next stage (in this case `$group`) will act on the results of the first (`$match`).

Comment: can you post the results of `$match` and `$group` separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words):

> MongoDB supports text search for various languages. text indexes drop
>   language-specific stop words (e.g. in English, “the”, “an”, “a”,
>   “and”, etc.) and uses simple language-specific suffix stemming.

The problem with your data is that some of the records have the `language-specific` stop word, `a`, which is considered to be a stop word in [portugese](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_portuguese.txt) too. Some of the stop words include, and `a` is on top of the list.

```
a
ao
aos
aquela
aquelas
aquele
aqueles
aquilo
as
até
com
como
```

These words are **never** indexed, and hence whenever you query for stop words, you get no results.

At the same time, If you query for `b`, you would get results, since it is not a stop word and would be indexed.

Comment: You are right. I set the default language to "none" and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @BatScream do you know if there's a way to force MongoDB to search all words -- override their current behavior for stop words?